# Sentinel configuration file

Tags: redis, sentinel, redis-sentinel

When adding a master to Sentinel, I always add the entries by editing `sentinel.conf`, but I often find out that application is being rewritten by another user (Sentinel).

I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate and an efficient way to add hosts to Sentinel without the need to edit the config file manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure sentinel to monitor a new master at runtime.

Example:

```
SENTINEL MONITOR {cluster_name} {master_ip} {master_port} {quorum}
SENTINEL SET {cluster_name} auth-pass {password}
SENTINEL FLUSHCONFIG   # Force Sentinel to rewrite its configuration file
```

For additional information check out the Redis Sentinel docs:
https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#reconfiguring-sentinel-at-runtime

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this really helpful!